# /etc/rc*: Why does this command stop NFS services from starting at boot?

Tags: boot, rename, nfs, services, etc

I recently found this [home networking tutorial](http://michaelminn.com/linux/home_network/) surprisingly enlightening. However, there is one thing I don't understand:

> Disabling NFS Start On Boot: If you are not planning on regularly
>   accessing files via NFS, you should not leave the NFS server running
>   and vulnerable to outside attacks. The startup scripts for NFS are in
>   the /etc/rc* directories and you should rename them with the K prefix
>   instead of the S prefix so they do not start at boot time:

the tutorial then gives the following command:

```
sudo rename s/S/K/ /etc/rc*/*nfs*
```

I have never really understood the way /etc/rc*/ works. But I assume there are certain directories in which the `service servicename start` scripts are always run, right? That's just a guess.

So, in this case, why does renaming these have an effect? How does the naming of directories affect this particular instance? What does that rename command actually do? Why does the new directory name ensure that NFS is not started at boot time?

Comment: that rename command also moves S01mountkernfs.sh -- in case anyone reading this uses it. bad idea for newer kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts in the /etc/rc?.d directories that start with S are used to start services.  Scripts that start with K are used to stop (kill) services.  By renaming all the NFS related init scripts starting with S to start with K, you insure that NFS services are never started by default.